# The line $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of the function$ y = f(x) $ if at least one of the following statements is true:

Tags: calculus

> The line $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of the function$ y = f(x) $ if at least one of the following statements is true:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\pm \infty$$
>
> $$\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=\pm \infty$$

Now how to recognize point $a$ .

for ex :

$$f(x)=\frac{\tan x+2}{\cos x+1}$$

$$\lim_{x\to a^{\pm}} \frac{\tan x+2}{\cos x+1}=\pm \infty$$

what is $a$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) \to \pm \infty \implies \frac{1}{f(x)} \to 0$$

Thus we need -

$$\frac{\cos x+1}{\tan x+2}\to 0 \implies \cos x+1\to 0 \implies x \to 2k\pi \pm \pi $$

Thus, $a=2k\pi \pm \pi$

Comment: do for all functions We have to write :?

$$f(x) \to \pm \infty \implies \frac{1}{f(x)} \to 0$$

Comment: @Almot1960 Yes, it's true for all kind of functions. You can think this logically too. We need the denominator to be tending to $0$ so that the function's value become so large that it tends to infinity.